# Log combination of keyboard

Tags: c#

How can log a combination of key strokes in a RichTextBox such as (Ctrl + shift + X) or (Ctrl + X)? Is there any way to separate this combination to key and Modifiers? so when I want to log these, I can separate them in something like (Modifier = Ctrl , Key = X)?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept keypresses in child controls by overriding Form.ProcessKeyPreview().  In that method, as long as the richtextbox has the focus, you can handle the keyboard message.

Comment: Well I am using a RichTextBox inside a WPF UserControl. My RichTextBox is a System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox. Any idea? thanks

Comment: but it has PreviewKeyUp nad PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: use PreviewKeyDown if you want to capture the keys when they press the key down, and PreviewKeyUp if you want to capture the keys when they let go of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the [Control.ModifierKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984219(VS.71).aspx) to see if the control and/or shift keys were used.